# login a webpage using python and display the result in the browser

Tags: python, authentication, browser

I'm a beginner in python and as a learning project i decided to just make a little script to lunch a webpage and log into it. Now after doing lots of googling (got many messy bits and piece of knowlegde) i found out that each website have it own way of handling login requests, and that there was many ways to emulate an instance of a browser to retrieve and post data ( urllib2, selenium, twill and blablabla).

So I know it is possible to log in into a website from python ( for a specific site and using a specific way) but I can't seem to  display the logged page in a browser.

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: We can't really help you without some code. Please post some, and if at all possible, maake it an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: It is unclear whether you want to login on an existing webpage or if you want to display a login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think selenium can do this job.

code snippet:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox 
browser.get(yoursite) # Load page 
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("email") # Find the query box 
elem.send_keys(email) 

ps = browser.find_element_by_name("password") # Find the query box 
ps.send_keys(passwd + Keys.RETURN)
```

this piece of code will drive your firefox to open the logged page.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for, however this it always open in a new instance of the browser , it is possible to open the web page in a tab instead ?

Comment: I'm also learning selenium; I believe there is a way to open a tab, but I don't know how to do it. I am reading the python doc of selenium now.